# Understanding proof of Rosen on GCD of two integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, gcd-and-lcm

I was referring Elementary Number Theory and its Applications by Kenneth Rosen (6th Ed., p. $95$).

My main object is to understand a proof of the following theorem given by the author (but not the other proofs; I am not trying to duplicate a question, but I am trying to understand assertion made by author.)

> **Theorem 3.8** The greatest common divisor of the integers $a$ and $b$, not both $0$, is the least positive integer that is an integral linear combination of $a$ and $b$.

> **Method of Proof:**  **Step (1)** Let $d$ be the least positive integer that is a linear combination of $a$ and $b$.

> **Step $2$:** We will show that $d|a$ and $d|b$. [I am skipping proof, since my main question is later.]

> **Step $3$:** Let $c$ be a common divisor of $a$ and $b$. We will show that $c|d$. [ Again, I am skipping proof of this.]

After this, author asserts the following:

> From Theorem 3.8, we immediately see that the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$ can be written as a linear combination of these integers.

**Question:** I don't understand **how he made this assertion from above proof**?

More specifically, I thought about proof as follows:
$$
\Big{(}d=\mbox{least positive integer, which is integral combination of $a$ and $b$}\Big{)} \,\, \Longrightarrow \,\,  \Big{(} d=gcd(a,b)\Big{)}
$$
and Steps 1 to 3 give proof of this.

BUT how the author asserts bout the converse of this again from steps 1 to 3, I am not getting.

Comment: Are you asking (a) about the proof of the theorem or (b) about the assertion that is *after* the theorem and its proof?

Comment: Step 1,2,3 (and its proofs, given by Rosen)- clear to me. Assertion after step 3 - not clear to me.

Comment: But the theorem already says that $\text{gcd}(a,b)$ is a linear combination of $a$ and $b$. It says even more: that it is the least positive integer that is such a linear combination. So the assertion is just a restatement that yes, the gcd can be written as a linear combination of $a$ and $b$, by Theorem 3.8. What is the unclear thing then?

Comment: I edited question (at the end); I hope, my question will be clearly visible.

Comment: Perhaps you missed the observation at the top of the proof that there *is* a number $d$ that is the least positive integer that is an integer linear combination of $a$ and $b$. Then the theorem shows that this $d$ *equals* the gcd. So the gcd *equals* this $d$, which is an integer linear combination of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Now someone has downvoted your question, I do not know why. After the edit, it seems to be a valid question about a confusion over what a theorem says, and probably quite answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Theorem 3.8, in a similar way to how you wrote it
$$gcd(a,b)= d = \text{least positive integer that is an integral linear combination of a and b}$$
where the assertion says that
$$gcd(a,b)=\text{linear combination of a and b}$$

This is clearly true, as the least positive integer linear combination is a linear combination.

Answer (score 0):

$k$ is a common factor of 12 and 18.  That is to say, $k|12$ and $k|18$.

$k$ is also divisible by $1$, $2$, $3$, and $6$.

We can conclude $k$ is the gcd of 12 and 18.

That's what the proof is doing.